# Slurm - Execute a lot of serial jobs parallel

Tags: slurm, hpc

Batch script to run many serial jobs parallel on a HPC with slurm

I want to run a large number of independent serial jobs in parallel using slurm. However, I run into the maximum number of 100 jobs that a user can submit. Therefore only 100 jobs are processed simultaneously in my script.

Is there a better way that I can submit the complete simulation as one big job?

```
#!/bin/bash

max_jobs=100

# Set the directory where the simulation folders are located
dir="/work/parameter_study/"

# Loop over the parameter cases
for param_case in {0001..0216}_sim; do
    cd $dir/$param_case
    
    # Loop over the Monte Carlo simulations
    for mcs_case in {0001..1500}_MCS; do
        cd $dir/$param_case/$mcs_case
        
        #sed -i -e 's/\r$//' a.out
            chmod 777 a.out
        
        # Check if max_jobs is exceeded
        while true
        do
          # Count rows without header
          job_count=$(squeue -h -t PD,R | wc -l) 
  
          if [ $job_count -lt $max_jobs ]
          then
            break
          fi
  
          sleep 0.5
        done


        # Submit a job for each simulation using the a.out file
            jobID=$(sbatch -p single -J ${param_case}_${msc_case} --wrap ./a.out) 
        echo "${jobID} ${param_case} ${mcs_case} - $(date '+%H:%M:%S')"
        
    done
done

# Wait for all jobs to finish
wait
```

Comment: You can try to submit a single job asking for as many processors as parallel tasks you need, and start several job steps inside, one for each task. But then you need as many resources as tasks and you will have to wait to have all of them available simultaneously. I don't recommend this approach.
Maybe an intermediate solution could help: make each job run several tasks, and let 100 of those jobs running simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you! I have the computing resources available from here [bwHPC](https://wiki.bwhpc.de/e/BwUniCluster2.0/Batch_Queues). Since I have about 300000 individual jobs, it is impossible to have so many tasks in parallel. 
Do I understand your suggestion correctly? To create individual jobs in which 100 independent parallel jobs are calculated? For this I would need 1 node and 100 tasks, isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly: you will need #<individual jobs>/#<individual jobs in each SLURM job> jobs. Each of this jobs will ask for #<individual jobs in each SLURM job> tasks of 1 CPU each. The number of nodes is not relevant. These jobs can be submitted as a job array or independently, it won't make much difference, it will only affect submission and ease of management.

Comment: Using one or several job arrays to launch the serial jobs is also an option. I'm not sure how the 100 jobs limit works, so I don't know if what I said is possible in your particular configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I had a closer look at the job arrays and developed a batch script, which I can run via `sbatch -p single array.sh`. But now I have the problem that I can submit a maximum of 100 at a time on the cluster , before `AssocGrpJobsLimit appears`. So I can't make the array bigger than 100. Do you have a suggested solution for this?

Comment: It looks like despite being a job array, each sub-job counts as a job. You will have to group your tasks in each job, so each SLURM job runs several of your tasks.

Comment: Yes, I start job groups. However, the jobs within a group are executed seriell and not  parallel. Below I have posted my current code.

Comment: If what you posted is not an answer, better update your question.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 300000 individual jobs. So to execute in parallel, I am assuming you can run 40 tasks per node at the same time. So you need 7500 nodes to run your all tasks the same time. It is unrealistic to get such huge allocation based on your cluster.

So, I would recommend consider the following. Based on your job waiting time, scheduling, you have to come up with the ideal number of nodes you can request per job submission to get a decent job waiting time. If it is **N**, then run as many jobs (sbatch submission) as the following.

```
Total_job_submissions= #number of tasks/( #max-tasks-per-node * N )
```

#number of tasks and #max-tasks-per-node varies based on your job queue.

I would recommend you to look into [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) also.

To run your jobs in parallel in the batch script provided, you just need to do the following.

```
for (( run=$START_NUM; run<=END_NUM; run++ )); do
  echo This is SLURM task $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, run number $run
  
  mcs_number=$((run - (-1 + SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID) * PER_TASK))
  
  param_case=$(printf "%04d" $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID)_sim
  mcs_case=$(printf "%04d" $mcs_number)_MCS
  mcs_dir=$dir$param_case/$mcs_case
  cd $mcs_dir
  chmod 777 a.out
  srun -n 1 ./a.out &
  
done

wait
```

Adding `&` will make `srun` run `a.out` in background and multiple instances of srun will be run in parallel. `wait` command at the end ensures that all jobs are finished before exiting from the script.

Answer (score 1):

Thats my batch script to run a job array. I can call this with:

> sbatch -p single array.sh

Each array starts 100 jobs, in which 1500 calculations are executed one after the other. Is there a way to execute these 1500 single a.out not serially but in parallel?

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=mega_array       # Job name
#SBATCH --nodes=1                   # Use one node
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                  # Run a single task
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1gb           # Memory per processor
#SBATCH --time=14:00:00             # Time limit hrs:min:sec
#SBATCH --array=1-100               # Array range

pwd; hostname; date

PER_TASK=1500

START_NUM=$(( ($SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID - 1) * $PER_TASK + 1 ))
END_NUM=$(( $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID * $PER_TASK ))

echo This is task $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, which will do runs $START_NUM to $END_NUM

dir="/work/"

for (( run=$START_NUM; run<=END_NUM; run++ )); do
  echo This is SLURM task $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, run number $run
  
  mcs_number=$((run - (-1 + SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID) * PER_TASK))
  
  param_case=$(printf "%04d" $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID)_sim
  mcs_case=$(printf "%04d" $mcs_number)_MCS
  mcs_dir=$dir$param_case/$mcs_case
  cd $mcs_dir
  chmod 777 a.out
  ./a.out 
  
done
```

Comment: Yes, you just need to use `srun -n 1 ./a.out  &`  and add `wait` command after the for loop. See my below answer.